# How I can send or recive UNICODE messages using python?

Tags: python, unicode, sms

i did not know much about python but sending sms message using pyserial is easy :

```
    self.ser.write('ATZ\r')
    time.sleep(1)
    self.ser.write('AT+CMGF=0\r')
    time.sleep(1)
    self.ser.write('''AT+CMGS="''' + self.recipient + '''"\r''')
    time.sleep(1)
    self.ser.write(self.content + "\r")
    time.sleep(1)
    self.ser.write(chr(26))
    time.sleep(1)
```

and there is many tutorials about sending or reciving sms using python and AT commands, but i really confused about using PDU and create proper AT command for sending unicode messages :(

what i have to do or whick module must use to send unicode (specially arabic/persian) messages?

i found pygsm and pygsmmodem modules, they look good but i can not found any easy document or tutorial or sample code for them...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with pyserial, but would this work?

```
self.ser.write(u'unicodestring')
```

Notice the **u** before the string, which declares it as unicode.